# How to upload file in relative directory

Tags: java, liferay

I have made a application where we can upload any file which will save in our local given directory. I want to modify it, i want to add a drop down (with multiple option i.e floor, store, section) for department. i.e if we want to upload a file in 'Store' folder, we can choose 'Store' option and the file will uploaded to the 'Store' folder. Same for 'Floor' and 'Section'.
I just need any example link for that.
i have made it in liferay.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;


import com.liferay.portal.kernel.upload.UploadPortletRequest;
import com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil;
import com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;

public class UploadDirectory extends MVCPortlet {

    private final static int ONE_GB = 1073741824;

    private final static String baseDir = "/home/xxcompny/workspace";

    private final static String fileInputName = "fileupload";

    public void upload(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(request);

        long sizeInBytes = uploadRequest.getSize(fileInputName);

        if (uploadRequest.getSize(fileInputName) == 0) {
            throw new Exception("Received file is 0 bytes!");
        }


        File uploadedFile = uploadRequest.getFile(fileInputName);

        String sourceFileName = uploadRequest.getFileName(fileInputName);



        File folder = new File(baseDir);



        if (folder.getUsableSpace() < ONE_GB) {
            throw new Exception("Out of disk space!");
        }


        File filePath = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + sourceFileName);


        FileUtils.copyFile(uploadedFile, filePath);
    }

}
```

JSP is here

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui"%>
<portlet:defineObjects />

<portlet:actionURL name="upload" var="uploadFileURL"></portlet:actionURL>

<aui:form action="<%= uploadFileURL %>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<select name="folder">
  <option value="store">Store</option>
  <option value="floor">Floor</option>
  <option value="department">Department</option>
</select>

<aui:input type="file" name="fileupload" />
<aui:button name="Save" value="Save" type="submit" />

</aui:form>
```

i want the file will upload in the belonging folder.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried for please?

Comment: Why need any example link for that?...create dropdown, validate selection and save file to selected option file directory.

Comment: Use switch case to set baseDir based on option selected by user.

Comment: `sourceFileName = response.getValue("folder");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had somewhat similar task to upload files to specified folders, so following is bit modified code as per your requirement:

```
public void upload(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
    throws Exception {

    UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(request);
    long sizeInBytes = uploadRequest.getSize(fileInputName);

    if (sizeInBytes == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Received file is 0 bytes!");
    }

    File uploadedFile = uploadRequest.getFile(fileInputName);
    String sourceFileName = uploadRequest.getFileName(fileInputName);

    /* selected folder from UI */
    String paramFolder = uploadRequest.getParameter("folder");

    byte[] bytes = FileUtil.getBytes(uploadedFile);

    if (bytes != null && bytes.length > 0) {
        try {
            /* Create folder if doesn't exist */
            File folder = new File(baseDir + File.separator + paramFolder);
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir();
            }

            /* Write file to specified location */
            File newFile = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + sourceFileName);            
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            fileOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            fileOutputStream.close();           
            newFile = null;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
            newFile = null;
            /* log exception */
        } catch (IOException io) {
            newFile = null;
            /* log exception */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the baseDir value? is it <tomcat>/webapps or <tomcat>/webapps/<our_webapp>?

Comment: For baseDir, you can use themeImagePath from your post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code

```
String user_selected_option=request.getParameter("userSel")
realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/files");
 destinationDir = new File(realPath+"/"+user_selected_option);

// save to destinationDir
```

Comment: Avoid code only answers. Please add some explanation to complete the answer. With no explanation and just code, this answer is not helpful as a solution (not to mention if it even solves the problem)

Comment: I want to pass user's selected option folder's name here "private final `static String baseDir = "/home/xxWe/Test/";` i mean to say if user select `floor`'s option the value of floor must be added after `/home/xxWe/Test/_User_Selected_option`