# Uploading images to liferay theme from a portlet

Tags: java, spring, liferay, liferay-theme

I have Liferay Spring Maven portlet, and a liferay theme. Now user will upload an image through the portlet. How can we place this in /webapps/theme/images? Any inbuilt liferay feature/API which would help us place the uploaded image into the theme?

Comment: I would never change the file _in_ the theme. What if your theme is in a WAR _file_? What about caching (usually the images form a WAR a cached in the browser)? What about security? You could upload the image into "Documents and Media" instead and include that one in the theme - that would be even easier to implement...

Comment: @Tobian I dropped the idea of uploading the image to theme, since next time when we release new version of the same, the uploaded data will be lost. Instead I will be uploading the image to a directory on the file system and read it from there.

Comment: Veeru A S, as upto your question, my answer has satisfied your requirement. You should accept the answer, if it has met your requirement so that it may be trusted as helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For file upload functionality, you can refer:
[How to upload file in relative directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707794/how-to-upload-file-in-relative-directory#answer-30725380)

For dynamic path of theme's image folder, you can get it through `ThemeDisplay` object as following:

**Action:**

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);    
String themeImagePath = themeDisplay.getPortalURL() + themeDisplay.getPathImage();
```

Where `request` can be `renderRequest` or `actionRequest`.

**JSP:**

```
<liferay-theme:defineObjects />

String themeImagePath = themeDisplay.getPortalURL() + themeDisplay.getPathImage();
```

Other relatively used options are `themeDisplay().getPathThemeCss()`, `themeDisplay().getPathJavaScript()` or `themeDisplay().getPathMain()`;

Comment: @Kumar, How do we upload at first place?

Comment: You can do File folder = new File(themeImagePath); like this.

Comment: I dropped the idea of uploading the image to theme, since next time when we release new version of the same, the uploaded data will be lost. Instead I will be uploading the image to a directory on the file system and read it from there. Thanks for your response Kumar

Comment: My answer on "How to upload file in relative directory" reveals how to upload image to local directory.